Quadratic equation with diagonal matrices
Suppose the following quadratic equation
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{D}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x}-2\mathbf{D}^{T}\mathbf{B}diag(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x})\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c} & =0,
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{A}(n-2,n-2)$, $\mathbf{B}(n-2,n-2)$
are the diagonal matrices, $\mathbf{D}(n-2,n)$ is
the difference tridiagonal matrix
$$
\mathbf{D}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}\right],
$$
and $\mathbf{x}(n,1)$, $\mathbf{c}(n,1)$ are the column vectors.
Is there any analytic solution of this equation for the variable $\mathbf{x}$?
Thanks for your help...

@ user1551 :  Thanks, typo was corrected...
